# android toolbar sometimes showing activity names and sometimes not

Tags: android

My app has different behaviour for the toolbar. In one case, it shows the name of the activity, in others not. I cant spot a difference in xmls that would explain it. Any idea why they behave so differently?

Activity without Text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ScreenMenu">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_screen_menu" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content xml for act without text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.ce.activizor.ScreenActivities"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_screen_menu"
android:background="@color/background">

<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            style="@style/AppTheme.Button_prim_sec"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Calendar"
            android:id="@+id/btn_screen_menu_cal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/AppTheme.Button_prim_sec"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="What's on"
            android:id="@+id/btn_screen_menu_whatson"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            style="@style/AppTheme.Button_prim_sec"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Friends"
            android:id="@+id/btn_screen_menu_friends"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/AppTheme.Button_prim_sec"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Notifications"
            android:id="@+id/btn_screen_menu_notifications"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/AppTheme.Button_prim_sec"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Activities"
            android:id="@+id/btn_screen_menu_act"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/AppTheme.Button_prim_sec"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Add event"
            android:id="@+id/btn_screen_menu_addevent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for the activity that shows the title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ScreenActivities">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_screen_activities" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.ce.activizor.ScreenActivities"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_screen_activities"
android:background="@color/background">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et_activity_new_activity"
    android:hint="new activity"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    style="@style/AppTheme.Button_prim_sec"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add activity"
    android:id="@+id/btn_activity_new_activity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_activity_new_activity"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv_activity_all_activities"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_activity_new_activity"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
This one displays the activity name on the phone (see right pic)

[image]

Also, one problem I had with the activity that does not show the text was that I had to add a relative layout as first layer as otherwise, the toolbar would be covering part of the linear layout.is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First check for `android:label` tag for activites in manifest file. For some, it might be mentioned and for some it might be missing.
2. To add a title, use

`mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");`

3. To remove a title, use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: thanks, that was it - no label in the manifest. So many places to look for things;)